# NiFi processor threads are getting blocked during session commit

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using a NiFi process flow to consumes the data from Kafka and the messages will go through multiple processors which will internally call the spring boot service to perform the business logics.
I am facing thread blocking issue while running this process in a 3 node NiFi cluster. Please find the thread dump.

"Timer-Driven Process Thread-490" #903 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fdf181bb000 nid=0xc99 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fde879fa000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal.fsync(LengthDelimitedJournal.java:356)
- waiting to lock <0x0000000748ad8080> (a org.apache.nifi.wali.LengthDelimitedJournal)
at org.apache.nifi.wali.SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.update(SequentialAccessWriteAheadLog.java:124)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:300)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.updateRepository(WriteAheadFlowFileRepository.java:257)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:406)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:342)
- locked <0x000000073e98e7f8> (a org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession)
at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Maybe you hit the limit of threads in nifi? Or a size limit of output queue?

Comment: Thanks for the response, But we have verified the same there s no such issues. The threads are getting blocked while doing session commit